# Evento focusin não funciona

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-eventos

Estou tentando usar o evento `focusin` num *event binding* no Angular 4 e ele não retorna o esperado para o evento.

Adicionei o evento numa `div` e para testar apenas lancei um `console.log` (para ver se estava acionando) só que não retorna nada. Quando troco para evento `click` ele retorna a mensagem no console, mas nem o `onfocus`, nem o `focusin` funcionaram.

Na página HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 border" (focusin)="painelAtivado()"><label class="subtitulos">Execução</label>
```

No `component.ts`:

```
painelAtivo(valor){
  this.flag = valor;
}
```

Comment: Será que DIVs têm esse evento?

Comment: Note que a função tem um nome diferente: `painelAtivo`. A div não recebe focus, a não ser que vc adicione `tabindex="0"`.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz o teste no [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwf8tv) e me parece que a função `(focusis)` funciona mesmo dentro de uma div.

Ao que me parece, é que a chamada da função esta errada. Então o código deve ficar

o html:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 border" (focusin)="painelAtivo(false)">...
```